# .net AppSettings historical trivia

Tags: .net

One of the previous developers where I work habitually, consistently used:

```
 ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Foo"].ToString()
```

It twigs me a bit since AppSettings collection items are already strings, but I got to wondering: way back in the ancient days of .net 1.0 and 1.1, did the collection store its items as type Object necessitating the ToString() call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `AppSettings` has always been a `NameValueCollection` with a `string` key and a `string` value.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

As John already mentioned, `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` is a `NameValueCollection` which returns it's items as Strings.

Personally, I hate to see this kind of code... people attaching a ToString() call to just about every property, regardless of whether it returns a string in the first place. Unfortunately, I get to see it all too often. My guess is that it makes people feel comforted... somehow, as if they're following recommended guidelines for writing beautiful code. :P

What they don't seem to realize is that calling `ToString()` on a Null object will throw an exception. For instance, in your example, if the "Foo" key did not exist in the AppSettings section of Configuration, a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown by the code.

Comment: +1 for pointing that out, maybe he even setup the code to catch that exception to tell the user that the key doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

no the appsettings in 1.1 is NameValueCollection of strings, i was reviewing a solution in vs2003 and i also find the ToString() while getting the appsettings; maybe it is a developer habit